# Image Cropper failed to start a new activity from the OnActivityResult

Tags: android, image

I am trying to pick an image from a GalleryActivity which contains a GridView of my local gallery images and start a CropActivity, for which I am using an external library called Android Image Cropper. After the crop I want to start a new ConfirmPhotoActivity to confirm the image and start uploading to server etc.

Now after I cropped the image and clicked on the crop button it always takes me back to the GalleryActivity, and the logcat doesn't throw any error messages...

Please see relevant codes as below:

GalleryActivity:

```
    //set onClickListener to the grid image view.
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image " + imageURLs.get(position));

            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(mAppend + imageURLs.get(position));
            startCrop(imageUri);
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: starting crop image activity");

        }
    });

}

private void startCrop(Uri imageUri){
    CropImage.activity(imageUri)
            .setAspectRatio(1,1)
            .start(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null) {
            resultUri = result.getUri();

            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: imageUrl is" + resultUri.toString());
            String imageUrl = resultUri.toString();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ConfirmPhotoActivity.class).putExtra("croppedImageUrl", imageUrl));

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }


    }

}
```

ConfirmPhotoActivity

```
public class ConfirmPhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SquareImageView squareImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_photo);

    squareImageView = findViewById(R.id.confirm_photo_imageView);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String imageurl = intent.getStringExtra("croppedImageUrl");
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, squareImageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

        }
    });





}
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Actually I found that my Confirm Photo activity has started and my imageUrl has been successfully passed over to it. But the layout is not showing...

Comment: Ok, problem solved. I made a stupid mistake in the ConfirmPhotoActivity which makes it finishes right away...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        // handle result of pick image chooser
        if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage.
            if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(this, imageUri))
            {
                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                // no permissions required or already grunted, can start crop image activity
                startCropImageActivity(imageUri);
            }
        }

        // handle result of CropImageActivity
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                profileIV.setImageURI(result.getUri());

                /*Here you can start new activity by passing imageUri with intent*/
                profileImageFilepath = result.getUri().getPath();
                Log.d("cropImageUri", result.getUri().getPath());
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to select photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't have a profile image view widget in my Gallery activity though. Is it necessary to have a imageView to show the cropped image in the same activity before moving on to another one?